# Generating WAR using Gradle wrapper in a Grails application

Tags: grails

Is it possible to generate a WAR using the Gradle wrapper (ie. `gradlew`) that comes with a Grails application?

As far as I can tell, after listing all the available tasks, it doesn't seem like it's possible. If not, I wonder why it isn't.

Side note, using it to publish to Artifactory, which is cool IMO.

**Update #1**

```
me@workstation ~/ghi
$ ./gradlew help --task assemble
:help
Detailed task information for assemble

Path
     :assemble

Type
     Task (org.gradle.api.Task)

Description
     Assembles the outputs of this project.

Group
     build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.345 secs
```

**Update #2**

I tried the following command: `gradlew -Dgrails.env=xxx war`

`META-INF\grails.build.info` shows `grails.env=xxx`.

Seems like that would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you're looking for is

```
./gradlew assemble
```

and your war will be in `build/libs/`

Comment: Does it have the same params as `grails war`? I'd like to specify an environment when it creates the WAR file. ie. `grails -Dgrails.env=xxx war`

Comment: Note that `assemble` only creates a `.war` file if the `war` plugin is installed.  If the `war` plugin is not installed then `assemble` will create a `.jar` file.

Comment: The `war` plugin is installed by default in Grails 3, but that is good to know.